# counting number of cells in same row of two data ranges/columns with identical values. Excel

Tags: excel

I would like to count how often a number (>0) appears in the same row of both columns 1 and 2.

I.e. in the below example the answer should be 1 for value 19 in both cells A11 and B11 (but should ignore value 8 in cells A8 and B9).

I tried these formulas:

`=COUNTIF(A11, "=" & B11)` works for single cells, but extending it to `=COUNTIF(A2:A18, "=" & B2:B18)` returns 0 (Error message 'Formula omits adjacent cells).

I also tried `=COUNTIF(A2:A18, "= B2:B18")` which also returns 0. (Here B2:B18 is not recognised as a range).

```
column 1    column 2
0           0
0           0
X           X
6           X
6           14
7           X
8           X
12          8
16          X
19          19
21          16
29          16
31          13
36          23
94          58
189         104
193         112
```

I am using Office Professional Plus 2016.

Comment: how about inserting a third column generating 1 if they match. 0 otherwise. and then, sum over the third column

Comment: you can hide the third column.

Comment: Hi Frank, thanks a lot, this is really helpful!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A2:A18=B2:B18)*(A2:A18>0)*ISNUMBER(A2:A18))
```

Here, I am checking three conditions. **(1)** cells are equal **(2)** cell value is greater than zero and **(3)** cell value is a number. Change ranges in formula as required.

See image for reference:

[image]

Comment: Also thanks for this one. It took me some thinking, but now I understand the conditions. Not quite sure about the 'sumproduct' function though, but I will figure it out!

Comment: @annie - For details on sumproduct, see [this](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMPRODUCT-function-16753e75-9f68-4874-94ac-4d2145a2fd2e).